# Filemaker Pro MS SQL Server ODBC Driver Connection Failure

Tags: sql-server, azure, odbc, filemaker, dsn

I am trying to connect to one of my MS SQL Server databases with the Filemaker Pro ODBC driver. I am using the database service. However, whenever I try to connect to my database it sends either an error that it can't connect to the datasource or an error that the username or password is incorrect. I know the credentials I am using are correct because I can connect to my Jetbrains IDE and to the mssql library in node.js with the same credentials. Does anyone know what the problem could be? My database is running on Azure. Do any setting need to be changed in the driver based on using Azure that could cause the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify: Are you running SQL Server in a VM? Or are you using SQL Database Service?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am using the database service.

Comment: If you connect from FileMaker to SQL Server, you need Native SQL driver and not FileMaker ODBC. Are you using FMP ESS or ODBC Import? If it is ESS, check the version of SQL Server supported.